# DataGridCheckBoxColumn Checked change when Usercontrol Loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to change DataGridCheckBoxColumn checked property when usercontrol loaded.

Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid BorderThickness="0"  Name="grid_kaynak" Margin="1" MaxHeight="200" RowHeight="28" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFDCDBDB" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFDCDBDB" HeadersVisibility="None" Background="{x:Null}" LayoutUpdated="grid_kaynak_LayoutUpdated">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="check_kaynak" MaxWidth="27" >
                                                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

When I try checked change in Usercontrol_loaded event return "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." But when I try in buttonclick event it works! Just like this:

```
private void btn_kaynak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid_kaynak.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = grid_kaynak.Items[i];
            var mycheckbox = grid_kaynak.Columns[1].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;
            if ((bool)mycheckbox.IsChecked == false)
            {
                mycheckbox.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can that work in Usercontrol_loaded event?

Comment: Why not simply bind the DataGrid to a collection of Items with a bool, and set the binding to two ways?

Comment: I dont know this. How can I do it that?

Comment: If my answer was of any help to you please accept it !

Answer (score 1):

First, define a model for your `DataGridItem`:

```
public class Model:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool _checked;

    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _checked) return;
            _checked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Make sure that your model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface so that any changes in the `Checked` property will be reflected in the UI.

Second, in your main viewModel or in your mainWindow's codebehind, add an `ObservableCollection` that will hold your `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource`:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Model> _dgCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
    {
        new Model(){Checked = true},
        new Model(){Checked = false},
        new Model(){Checked = true},
    };
    public ObservableCollection<Model> DgCollection
    {
        get { return _dgCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _dgCollection)) return;
            _dgCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Also make sure that your main ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Finally, update your `DataGrid` In your `usercontrol` so that it will be populated withe `ObservableCollection`:

```
<DataGrid BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DgCollection}" Name="grid_kaynak" Margin="1" MaxHeight="200" RowHeight="28" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFDCDBDB" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFDCDBDB" HeadersVisibility="None" Background="{x:Null}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="check_kaynak" MaxWidth="27" Binding="{Binding Checked}">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Now you could handle your usercontrol's `Loaded` event from your mainWindow codebehind or viewModel:

```
<Window ...
   Title="MainWindow" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Name="MainWindows" >
   <Grid>
       <local:UserControl1 Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The event handler:

```
 private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var model in DgCollection)
        {
            model.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Ps: The `DataContext` of the Window above is set to its codebehind using: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`